# KSH-update : Get rows affected

Tags: sql, bash, teradata, ksh

Hello I'm querying a teradata database like that :

```
for  var in `db2 -x  "$other_query"`; 
do
 query_update_date="update test SET date =Null WHERE 
name_test='$var '"
 db2 -v "$query_update_date"
done
```

My query is executed but what I would like to print the query_update_date only  when one row or more is affected (changed ) by update.

Example :
    If I have
 First query of loop :

```
 query_update_date="update test SET date =Null WHERE 
name_test='John'"
```

and second query of the loop :

```
query_update_date="update test SET date =Null WHERE 
name_test='Jeff'"
```

and in my table before the query :

```
name_test         date
 Jeff             01/07/2016
 John             Null
```

After the query

```
name_test         date
 Jeff             Null
 John             Null
```

The date from John was already null , so it hasn't been affected by update.
 And

```
db2 -v "$query_update_date"
```

print my queries. What I want for previous example is to print in my logs only

```
query_update_date="update test SET date =Null WHERE 
name_test='Jeff'"
```

Comment: Copy paste a sample output you are expecting from the query, i.e. the value that is likely to be stored in the variable.

Comment: I'm going to edit the topic

Comment: In some cases, query_update_date won't affect row  because the date would already be Null. I don't need these queries my logs

Comment: So do you need to check if the variable is null or valid? `if [ ! -z "$query_update_date" ];` ?

Comment: `WHERE ... AND date is not null` will help counting the records changing.

Comment: @Inian not exactly, In my logs, I print the $query_update_date with    `db2 -v "$query_update_date"`    . But I want to print it only when I have at least one row affected by the update query.  What I get from `db2 -x  "$other_query"` is always  valid. But in some case, my update is unecessary because the row is already `Null`. For theses cases, I don't want to print the query.

Comment: @John: I will probably have to down-vote the question, because the information you keep providing is insufficient, and without the actual sample query output format, it is not possible to assist you further here!

Comment: @Inian I have edited the topic. Do you understand what I'm looking for ?

Comment: @John: looks better know, and I just want to know one last thing. Can you `echo` the OP from the script for the variable `$query_update_date` when the  `query_update_date="update test SET date =Null WHERE 
name_test='Jeff'"`. Will need it to process the variable

Comment: Will it have some strings  lile `UPDATED...' WHERE condition = ....` "`. I need to know the exact string for a valid update

Answer (score 0):

Take snapshots of the table before and after you execute the query.  Use whatever tools you like: how about (assuming SQL) **SPOOL** a **"SELECT * FROM T**" query into this file beforehand, and into that file afterwards.  Use the UNIX **diff** command to compare the two files, and merely count the length of its output:

> **LINES_OUT=$(diff oldResults newResults | wc -l)
>
>   if [[ $LINES_OUT = 0 ]]
>
>   then
>
>        # log the query, however you do that
>
>   fi**

If **$IS_ANY_DIFF** is true, log the query; otherwise, don't.